# how to use python-cassandra-driver to insert data with a custom timestamp

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I have a task that insert data into a cassandra table, but i donnot want to overwrite the records that have been inserted before, but the insert cql would overwrite existing data.

Fortunately, I find a operation of 'USING TIMESTAMP ', cql with larger timestamp will overwrite the smaller one, otherwise not. So with 'USING TIMESTAMP' i could use a custom timestamp to determine whether overwrite or not. It works fine in Cqlsh.

But it fails in python-cassandra-driver, how to make 'USING TIMESTAMP' work in python-cassandra-driver? My code is as follow:

```
insert_sql = ("INSERT INTO activate (rowkey, qualifier, info, act_date, log_time) "
              "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) "
              "USING TIMESTAMP %s")
insert_data = (a_string, a_string, a_string, a_string, a_string, a_custom_timestamp)
session.execute(insert_sql, insert_data)
```

Comment: Blake's advice below is sound. Focusing on your original question: your code should work as shown. What makes you think it does not work from the driver? Could it be an issue with resolution in your custom timestamp? How are you generating that?

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect use-case for setting custom timestamps. It's important to not abuse this feature because it can have many unintended side-effects and can ultimately lead to unreliable data.

Use Lightweight Transactions (LWT) instead (also use PreparedStatements instead of raw strings!)

```
stmt = session.prepare("
           INSERT INTO activate (rowkey, qualifier, info, act_date, log_time)
           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
           IF NOT EXISTS
           ")
results = session.execute(stmt, [arg1, arg2, ...])
```

Read more [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/insert_r.html) and [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_ltweight_transaction_t.html). LWT takes a performance hit from having to trigger a paxos consensus check, but it's better than a "read-then-write" approach.

Better yet, if you absolutely need to maximize write performance, consider modifying your data model to include a timestamp:

```
CREATE TABLE activate (
     rowkey text,
     insert_time timestamp,
     qualifier text,
     info text,
     act_date timestamp,
     log_time timestamp, 
   PRIMARY KEY (rowkey, insert_time));
```

Comment: [But please note that using IF NOT EXISTS will incur a non negligible performance cost (internally, Paxos will be used) so this should be used sparingly](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#insertStmt)
in fact, i have uesd **IF NOT EXISTS** before, but the write performance is out of my control, in order to strengthen the real-time quality, i need a faster method. 
And my primary key is (rowkey, qualifier), the reason is that I have to drop the data with same primary key, just remain the first inserted one. So maybe it's not appropriate to change the data model.